# What's the easiest security mode for implementation in WCF?

Tags: wcf

What's the easiest security mode for implementation in WCF when:

- Both client and service are .NET applications.
- Client and service are negotiating over internet.
- SSL in not available.
- Port 80 (web) is preferred for communication.
- And Using a x 509 certificate should be the last option (same credentials in configuration file at both sides is preferred, if possible)

Comment: There's no simple "Security is on" vs "Security is off" option, in any situation. You need to define what secrets you're trying to protect, and then assess solutions against how well those goals are met.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Security means a lot of things:

- Authentication
- Authorization
- Confidentiality
- Integrity

To name a few. You need to decide what are your requirements for each.

Since SSL is not available you must use message level security. But assuming machines do not necessarily live on the same windows domain you cannot use windows authentication and must use x.509 certificate, at least on the serve side. So:

```
<customBinding authenticationMode="usernameForCertificate" />
```

where the client authenticates with a username and the server with a certificate (client need to install this certificate).

You could also use a WSHttpBinding with all default settings except:

```
messageClientCredentialType=UserName
```

In which case client does not need to install the certificate, it gets it automatically in runtime via negotiation.

Answer (score -1):

> > > Both client and service are .NET applications.

Take a look here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee707353(v=vs.91).aspx